# About JVM creation

Tags: java, jvm

When does the instance of JVM created? If 2 JVMs running parallel in the same system,whether the program that running in one Jvm can access the program that is running in another one? I heard that this is true. Is that so?

Comment: JVM is a process generally speaking, processes can communicate via sockets, pipes, shared memory, etc, however by definition they cannot access each other memory. Also are you talking about android or you have some other OS in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Two JVMs can only talk to each other using inter-process communication methods, just as two non-JVM processes would do.

i.e. they need to use a shared database, a message queue, sockets -- or even plain files to share data.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. You'll have two strictly separated virtual machines and objects living in one VM can't send messages to objects living in the other one or share data.

The virtual machine is started/created/... when you call `java`.

Comment: But you can run more that one JVM at the same time, independent of each other. Also when is the instance of JVM created?

Comment: @Alpine - of course, as many JVM as you like. But **each** runs independently from the others.

Comment: @Andreas_D - your ans **No** means, program running in one JVM cant access program running on another JVM does that access means taking control over objects or sharing data. As @tgdavies  said below that `Two JVMs can only talk to each other using inter-process communication methods, just as two non-JVM processes would do.` Please put more light on JVM communication if possible share any link.

Comment: @PardeepSharma 'Programs' don't talk to each other and the concept of 'program' is questionable for what iss, let's say, 'inside' a jvm. You can run a lot of 'programs' or services or whatever in a single jvm. There's only one main thread, but you can spawn (almost) as many as you want and have each thread represent some sort of 'program'. See J2EE for example, where a single JVM contains a web server and all deployed applications.

But a jvm does not have direct access to any object inside a different jvm. They don't share stacks or heaps.

Comment: @Andreas_D `But a jvm does not have direct access to any object inside a different jvm. They don't share stacks or heaps` Your this point is absolutely right. Now there is another query in my mind then how All Data Node and NN talk with each other. I'm bit confused with all Hadoop Internal architecture, how exactly it works and how it manages it's resources. What is role of JVM Memory and Cores(Processors). Can you please help me with a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

One instance of JVM is created per process. That is, one independent instance is created every time you run `java.exe`. Such JVMs are completely separate of each other, therefore you can even run different versions of JVM on the same machine.

There is no transparent way for JVMs to communicate with each other. However, java comes bundled with RMI, an inter-process communication tool, which allows almost transparent cross-JVM communication. But of course it involves specifying other JVM's hostname and port of communication, so you need to a bit of work to get it to work correctly.

Comment: If both my JVMs are on the same machine, then I can use a single RMI registry, but if I have the two JVMs on different machines then I would require two RMI registry, one on each of the machines running the JVMs.

Comment: @Alpine only one rmi registry is needed. You can run rmi registry either inside your server application (in the save JVM), or as a separate process on the same or different machine using `rmiregistry` command.